# Can you reduce two similar response variables into a single response variable in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset which has two response variables: 1) proportion of movements during checks (called "During") and 2) proportion of movements between checks (called "Between"). I am using this dataset to determine if tadpole behavior is impacted by my treatments (control vs. artificial light at night) during the day and night. The two response variables (During and Between) are not correlated with one another. I am wondering if I can reduce the two response variables into a single variable (let's call it, "Activity"). I have done some reading about dimension reduction, but it seems to mostly apply to predictor variables rather than response variables. I am not too familiar with the approach so I could be wrong about this. If it is appropriate to reduce these two variables into one, how would I code this into R? My plan is to use the variable "Activity" as a response variable in a generalized linear mixed effects model like this:

```
activityglmer <- glmer(Activity ~ Treatment*Light + (1|Tadpole_ID), data = move_df)
```

Thanks in advance! Here is a small bit of my data for context:

```
     Tadpole_ID Treatment Light     During   Between
1           1   Control   Day 0.38461538 0.4615385
2           1   Control Night 0.27272727 0.8000000
3           2   Control   Day 0.00000000 0.9230769
4           2   Control Night 0.09090909 0.8000000
5           3   Control   Day 0.15384615 0.6923077
6           3   Control Night 0.00000000 0.8000000
7          21      ALAN   Day 0.46153846 0.7692308
8          21      ALAN Night 0.36363636 0.7000000
9          22      ALAN   Day 0.23076923 0.7692308
10         22      ALAN Night 0.09090909 1.0000000
11         23      ALAN   Day 0.30769231 0.6153846
12         23      ALAN Night 0.00000000 0.6000000
```

Comment: `pc <- prcomp(move_df[4:5], scale = TRUE); summary(pc); pc$x` can be used 
to find the find the principal components -- you would use the first.  
If you would rather just pick one of the two original variables then `pairs(move_df[4:5])` will quickly suggest which can predict the other better.

Comment: Although this has been bounced to CV as statistical, it seems more a substantive question to me. During and Between sound different and your data example shows that they can be very different. Just possibly there is a better analysis by reshaping the data to a single response  variable and twice as many observations and an indicator for During versus Between.  Or just possibly the mean of these two is helpful. Hard to say more without subject-matter expertise or a lengthier discussion of your goals.

Comment: Applying PCA is a matter of taste, but if there is a weak correlation between the responses I doubt that the PCs will be helpful. .

Answer (score 0):

From the sample you have supplied, it looks like `Activity` is quite different between the two `Time`s:  `During` and `Between`.  If it makes sense to treat `Activity` as one type of measurement, you will probably still want to keep `Time` in the model.  I don't know what model would make sense in your case, but it might be something like:

```
activityglmer = glmer(Activity ~ Treatment*Light + Time + (1|Tadpole_ID), 
                      data = Long)
```

Attached are histograms for the data you supplied, and below is some code that converts your wide format data to long format.

```
if(!require(lattice)){install.packages("lattice")}
if(!require(tidyr)){install.packages("tidyr")}

Data = read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, text="

Tadpole_ID Treatment Light     During   Between
         1   Control   Day 0.38461538 0.4615385
         1   Control Night 0.27272727 0.8000000
         2   Control   Day 0.00000000 0.9230769
         2   Control Night 0.09090909 0.8000000
         3   Control   Day 0.15384615 0.6923077
         3   Control Night 0.00000000 0.8000000
        21      ALAN   Day 0.46153846 0.7692308
        21      ALAN Night 0.36363636 0.7000000
        22      ALAN   Day 0.23076923 0.7692308
        22      ALAN Night 0.09090909 1.0000000
        23      ALAN   Day 0.30769231 0.6153846
        23      ALAN Night 0.00000000 0.6000000
")

library(tidyr)

Long = pivot_longer(Data, 
                    c("During", "Between"), 
                    names_to="Time", values_to="Activity")

head(Long)


###     OBS Tadpole_ID Treatment Light Time    Activity
###   <int>      <int> <fct>     <fct> <chr>      <dbl>
### 1     1          1 Control   Day   During     0.385
### 2     1          1 Control   Day   Between    0.462
### 3     2          1 Control   Night During     0.273
### 4     2          1 Control   Night Between    0.8  
### 5     3          2 Control   Day   During     0    
### 6     3          2 Control   Day   Between    0.923

library(lattice)

histogram(~ Activity | Time,
          data=Long, layout=c(1,2), col="darkgray")
```

[image: histograms]